# Should time complexity of Juggling algorithm be O(n)?

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Time Complexity of Juggling algorithm for array rotation(Suppose array is rotated for 'd' times) is computed as O(n), where 'n' is the size of the array. But, for any number of rotation(i.e. for any value of 'd'), the algorithm runs exactly for n times. So, shouldn't the time complexity of the algorithm be "Theta(n)" instead of O(n) ? It always loops for n times in any case.If not, can anyone provide a test case where it doesn't run for exactly 'n' times?

Answer (score 2):

Saying that `f` is in `Θ(n)` is the same thing as saying that it's in both `O(n)`  and `Ω(n)`. Colloquially, `O(·)` is often used when `Θ(·)` would be more precise. But a function in `Θ(n)` is definitely *also* in `O(n)`.